# How can I match on the comparison of two fields in the same document in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate, aggregation

I am at a stage in my Mongo aggregation where I have documents like this:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId('648031bd784fbf6081de41cf'),
  "orgId": 1,
  "applications": {
    "_id": ObjectId('6479ddda073ced427d04e9dd'),
    "orgId": 1,
    "firstTimeInstalled": [
      {
        "refId": ObjectId('648031bd784fbf6081de41cf'),
        "installDate": "2023-06-08T09:18:49.233+00:00"
      },
      {
        "refId": ObjectId('6479ddda073ced427d04e9dd'),
        "installDate": "2023-06-08T09:18:49.233+00:00"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to only match on documents where applications.firstTimeInstalled does not contain an object where refId is equal to the _id in the root of the document.

I've tried to do this:

```
{
  $match: {
    "applications.firstTimeInstalled.refId": {
      $ne: "$_id"
    }
  }
}
```

But I still get documents back that doesn't meet the criteria so doesn't seem to work.

The thing that confuses me even more is that even if I do this:

```
{
  'applications.firstTimeInstalled.refId': {
    $nin: [ ObjectId('647746cfd9baa823f877c08f') ]
  }
}
```

As you can see I inject the _id manually, but this still returns the document... How is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a possible solution is to `$map` through the `firstTimeInstalled` array and if the mapped array has [`$anyElementTrue`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/anyElementTrue/) it means there is an element with `_id === refId`.
So take the negation with `$not`

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $not: {
          $anyElementTrue: {
            $map: { 
              input: "$applications.firstTimeInstalled",
              in: { $eq: [ "$$this.refId", "$_id" ] }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7LcnFuhqiI1)

**EDIT - better solution**
a better solution [here](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/i-want-to-match-where-a-field-of-an-array-of-objects-is-not-equal-to-the-id/230596/2?u=schach_schach) thanks to [turivishal](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/u/turivishal)
quoting

> The `$match` can’t allow checking the internal fields condition directly, you need to use `$expr` operator, `$not` and `$in` operator to match your condition,

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $not: {
          $in: ["$_id", "$applications.firstTimeInstalled.refId"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EZK1WM9TYbm)

Comment: seems to work in Mongo Playground, but for some reason when I make the aggregation in MongoDB Compass I get the following error:

`PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: $anyElementTrue's argument must be an array, but is null`

Comment: @TheStranger are there documents where firstTimeInstalled is not existing

Comment: yes, but they are filtered away in a stage far prior to this..

Comment: this happen when  `input: null,` that is `applications.firstTimeInstalled` doesnt exist. for good measure try with `input: { $ifNull: [ "$applications.firstTimeInstalled", [] ] }`  https://mongoplayground.net/p/4lXBBp3Lm_D

Comment: When I do that, I get back the document, but it still returns the document that I'm trying to filter away. And btw applications.firstTimeInstalled does exist, I can see it in the stage...

Comment: that means the filtering is not done prior?

Comment: prior to the match stage I only get one document, which is the one posted in the OP. And it contains `applications.firstTimeInstalled` just like in the OP. I've tried just to test it to say `{ 'applications.firstTimeInstalled.refId': { $nin: [ ObjectId('647746cfd9baa823f877c08f') ] } }`, and even that doesn't filter away the document... That's odd..

Comment: use `$nin` for arrays that have just values not objects for example if `"applications.firstTimeInstalled": [ ObjectId("648031bd784fbf6081de41cf"), ObjectId("6479ddda073ced427d04e9dd") ]` you can do `"applications.firstTimeInstalled": { $nin: [ ObjectId("648031bd784fbf6081de41cf") ] }`

Comment: The error I had was that I had a space at the end of my firstTimeInstalled field name in the database. Your solution works, thank you!!

Comment: @TheStranger there is a better solution